# AS3 Windows style drag and drop

Tags: actionscript-3, drag

I'm making a windows style app with different windows which contain different elements. I know how to code a drag and drop function to change the position of the windows on the stage but I'd like to use a single code for all windows without repeating infinite functions. My code is:

```
public function fl_WindowDrag(event: MouseEvent): void {
        instance.startDrag();
    }

    public function fl_WindowDrop(event: MouseEvent): void {
        instance.stopDrag();
    }
```

I'd like the istance name was retrived automatically from the selected window, is it possible?
I hope you understand my need
Any help is well accepted
Thanks in advance

```
package {

import flash.display.*;
import flash.text.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.ui.Mouse;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class MainTimeline extends MovieClip {

    //Variabili
    public var VFullscreen: int = 1;

    //Import var        
    public var VTerminal: Terminal = new Terminal();
    public var nTerminal:String;

    public function MainTimeline(): void {

        stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;

        //Import

        //Terminal
        VTerminal.x = 288;
        VTerminal.y = 384;
        stage.addChild(VTerminal);


        //Event Listeners
        //addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_BringToFront);
        VTerminal.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fl_WindowDrag);
        VTerminal.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fl_WindowDrop);
    }

    //public functions

    //Gestione Fullscreen

    public function fl_Fullscreen(event: MouseEvent): void {
        switch (VFullscreen) {
            case 0:
                stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
                VFullscreen = 1;
                break;
            case 1:
                stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.NORMAL;
                VFullscreen = 0;
                break;
        }
    }

    public function fl_FSCheck(event: Event): void {
        if (stage.displayState == StageDisplayState.NORMAL) {
            VFullscreen = 0;
        }
        if (stage.displayState == StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE) {
            VFullscreen = 1;
        }
    }

    //Primo Piano Finestre
    public function fl_BringToFront(event: MouseEvent): void {
        this.addChild(event.currentTarget as DisplayObject);
    }


    public function fl_WindowDrag(event: MouseEvent): void {
        event.currentTarget.startDrag();
        nTerminal = event.currentTarget.name.toString();
        trace(nTerminal);
    }

    public function fl_WindowDrop(event: MouseEvent): void {
        event.currentTarget.stopDrag();
    }

    //Chiusura
    public function fl_Close(event: MouseEvent): void {
        stage.nativeWindow.close();
    }

    //Apertura/Chiusura Terminal
    public function fl_Terminal(event: MouseEvent): void {
        if (contains(VTerminal)) {
            removeChild(VTerminal);
        } else {
            VTerminal.x = 288;
            VTerminal.y = 320;
            addChild(VTerminal);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways you can do this.
You can prepare base class for all windows wich will inherit this behavior and if you plan to design over a dozen of windows this is definitelly thing you should consider. Another way is to create sperarate class designed to only do this and register all windows you want to it.
But since you asking if this is even possible I would recommend you to try some third party libraries.

[GreenShock](http://greensock.com/TransformManager) has a good tool for this but i didn't use their libralies a while and I don't know what are their licecing programs.

In case you don't like it, you can use my code i made some time ago.
It's very easy to use but it's not fully implemented(can't rotate and such) and documentation is very weak but if you were interested i can help you with this.
All you need to do is pass objects you want to move along with some bassic properties:

```
TransformTool.addClient(target:InteractiveObject, operations:uint = 3, edgesMask:uint = 15, sizeBounds:Array = null, dragBounds:Array = null, grabRange:Number = 5):TransformData
```

- `terget` - that would be your window.
- `operations` - bit-flags representing type of transformation (scale, drag, rotate)
- `edgesMask` - bit-flags defining which edges should be involved in scaling operation (left, right, top, bottom) all these flags values as well as operations flags can be found in `TransformData` class.
- `sizeBounds` - array contian minimum and maximum size of scaled object accordingly for with and height.
- `dragBounds` - position boundries for draged object. Basically those are arguments for flash `Rectangle` class.
- `grabRange` - distance from mouse to edge in which you can grab and edge (or edges in case of corner). You can grab an edge also with mouse outside the object and  scale two separate objects edges at once.

So assuming `w` and `w2` are your windows, usage looks like this:

```
    TransformTool.addClient(w, TransforData.SCALE|TransformData.DRAG, TransformData.BOTTOM_EDGE|TransformData.RIGHT_EDGE, null, null, 10);
    TransformTool.addClient(w2, 3, 15, [20, 10, 350, 350], [100, 100, 600, 500], 10);
```

That is only this line required to use it.
You can also add listener if you would like to change cursor.

```
TransformTool.eventDispatcher.addEventListener(TransformToolEvent.EDGES_HIT, transformTestHit);
private function transformTestHit(e:TransformToolEvent):void 
{
    trace(TransformData(e.data).hitEdges);
}
```

Below is all the code involved. You can use it as you wish however be Aware that TransformTool is static class and uses only one stage instance.
I you want to develop app in Air and use native windows you would need to modify this code because  each navtive window instance has its own unique stage.

TransformTool class:

```
package utils  
{
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.InteractiveObject;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
    /**
     * ...
     * @author Audionysos
     */
    public class TransformTool
    {
        private static var clients:Vector.<TransformData> = new Vector.<TransformData>();
        private static var transforming:Vector.<TransformData> = new Vector.<TransformData>();
        private static var _stage:Stage;
        public static var checkEdgesOnMMove:Boolean = true;
        private static var _eventDispatcher:EventDispatcher = new EventDispatcher();

        public static function addClient(target:InteractiveObject, operations:uint = 3, edgesMask:uint = 15, sizeBounds:Array = null, dragBounds:Array = null, grabRange:Number = 5):TransformData {
            var sBR:Rectangle;
            var dBR:Rectangle;
            if (sizeBounds) sBR = new Rectangle(sizeBounds[0], sizeBounds[1], sizeBounds[2], sizeBounds[3]);
            if (dragBounds) dBR = new Rectangle(dragBounds[0], dragBounds[1], dragBounds[2], dragBounds[3]);
            var td:TransformData = new TransformData(target, operations, edgesMask, sBR, dBR, grabRange);
            if (operations & TransformData.SCALE) td.allowDrag = true;
            clients.push(td);

            if (stage) return td;
            if (!target.stage) target.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onStage);
            else { stage = target.stage; addStageListeners(); }
            return td;
        }

        /**
         * Return TransformData object associated with given target.
         * @param   target object associated with searched TransformData. 
         * @return  TransformData object associated with given target.
         */
        static public function getTransformData(target:InteractiveObject):TransformData {
            for (var i:int = 0; i < clients.length; i++){
                if (clients[i].targetObject == target) return clients[i];
            }return null;
        }

        /**
         * Mouse position relative to specifed object.
         * @param   target InteractiveObject or TransformData object.
         * @return Mouse position relative to specifed object.
         */
        static public function getTargetMouse(target:*):Point 
        {
            var t:InteractiveObject = target as InteractiveObject;
            if (!t && target as TransformData) t = TransformData(target).targetObject;
            else throw new Error ("property object must be of type InteractiveObject or TransformData");
            return new Point(t.parent.mouseX, t.parent.mouseY);
        }

        /**
         * Adds MOUSE_DOWN and MOUSE_UP listener for current stage;
         */
        static private function addStageListeners():void 
        {
            //trace("TT adding stage listeners");
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMDown);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMUp);
        }

        static private function onStage(e:Event):void 
        {
            //trace("TT client on stage");
            InteractiveObject(e.target).removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onStage);
            stage = InteractiveObject(e.target).stage;
            addStageListeners();
        }

        static private function onMUp(e:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            for (var i:int = 0; i < transforming.length; i++){
                transforming[i].isTransforming = false;
            }
            transforming =  new Vector.<TransformData>();
        }

        static private function onMDown(e:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            //trace("TT MousDown");
            findAffectedObjects();
        }

        static private function findAffectedObjects():void 
        {
            for (var i:int = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
                clients[i].hitEdges = findEdges(clients[i]);
                if (!clients[i].hitEdges) continue;
                //trace("TT got R", clients[i].hitEdges);
                transforming.push(clients[i]);
                clients[i].isTransforming = true;
                clients[i].updateMouseVector();
                stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMMove);
            }
        }

        static private function onMMove(e:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            //trace("Transforming", transforming.length);
            if (TransformTool.checkEdgesOnMMove) dispatchEdges();
            //trace("TT Moving");
            for (var i:int = 0; i < transforming.length; i++) {
                if (transforming[i].operations & TransformData.ROTATE) rotateTarget();
                //if (!checkEdgesOnMMove)
                transforming[i].updateMouseVector();
                scaleTarget(transforming[i]);
                fixSize(transforming[i]);
                fixPlacement(transforming[i]);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Performs fingEdges() operation on each client TransformData object and dispatches EDGES_HIT event if result is different form last hitEdges state;
         */
        static private function dispatchEdges():void 
        {
            for (var i:int = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
                if (clients[i].isTransforming) continue;
                var r:uint = findEdges(clients[i]);
                if (r != clients[i].hitEdges) {
                    clients[i].hitEdges = r;
                    _eventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(new TransformToolEvent(TransformToolEvent.EDGES_HIT, clients[i]));
                }
            }
        }

        static private function rotateTarget():void 
        {

        }

        /**
         * If a part of an object is outside defined dragBounds rectangle area it will move this object to closest allowed position.
         * @param   td
         */
        static public function fixPlacement(td:TransformData):void 
        {
            if (!td.dragBounds) return;
            td.targetObject.x = Math.max(td.targetObject.x, td.dragBounds.x);
            td.targetObject.x = Math.min(td.dragBounds.right - td.targetObject.width, td.targetObject.x);
            td.targetObject.y = Math.max(td.targetObject.y, td.dragBounds.y);
            td.targetObject.y = Math.min(td.dragBounds.bottom-td.targetObject.height, td.targetObject.y);
        }

        /**
         * Changes the object to fit min/max size defined in sizeBounds object of the transformation data.
         * @param   td
         */
        static public function fixSize(td:TransformData):void 
        {
            if (!td.sizeBounds) return;
            td.targetObject.width = Math.min(td.targetObject.width, td.sizeBounds.width);
            td.targetObject.width = Math.max(td.targetObject.width, td.sizeBounds.x);
            td.targetObject.height = Math.min(td.targetObject.height, td.sizeBounds.height);
            td.targetObject.height = Math.max(td.targetObject.height, td.sizeBounds.y);
        }

        /**
         * Scales the object accordingly to grabed edges and move of the mouse.
         * @param   td
         */
        static public function scaleTarget(td:TransformData):void 
        {
            //trace("TT mouse vector", td.mouseVector);
            var rD:Point = td.mouseVector//new Point(td.mouseVector.x * td.targetObject.parent.scaleX, td.mouseVector.y * td.targetObject.parent.scaleY); //relativeDisplacement
            if (td.hitEdges & TransformData.LEFT_EDGE) { td.targetObject.width -= rD.x; td.targetObject.x += rD.x; }
            if (td.hitEdges & TransformData.RIGHT_EDGE) { td.targetObject.width += rD.x; }
            if (td.hitEdges & TransformData.TOP_EDGE) { td.targetObject.height -= rD.y; td.targetObject.y += rD.y; }
            if (td.hitEdges & TransformData.BOTTOM_EDGE) { td.targetObject.height += rD.y; }

        }

        /**
         * Check if mouse position is in grab range to any of specified object edge.
         * @param   target examined object
         * @param   grabRange minimal distance from mouse position to edge of the object. 
         * @return  resul of the inspection.
         */
        static public function findEdges(td:TransformData):uint 
        {
            if (!isMouseNearTarget(td)) return 0;
            var t:InteractiveObject = td.targetObject;
            var gR:Number = td.grabRange;
            var r:uint;
            if (Math.abs(t.x - t.parent.mouseX) < gR && t.parent.mouseX) r |= TransformData.LEFT_EDGE;
            if (Math.abs(t.x + t.width- t.parent.mouseX) < gR) r |= TransformData.RIGHT_EDGE;
            if (Math.abs(t.y - t.parent.mouseY) < gR) r |= TransformData.TOP_EDGE;
            if (Math.abs(t.y + t.height - t.parent.mouseY) < gR) r |= TransformData.BOTTOM_EDGE;
            return r;
        }

        /**
         * Check if mouse relative position is cantained within target rectangle + grabRange;
         * @param   td object to examine.
         * @return  true if mouse is near object (edges can be grabbed);
         */
        static public function isMouseNearTarget(td:TransformData):Boolean 
        {
            td.updateMouseVector();
            var exRect:Rectangle = td.targetObject.getRect(td.targetObject.parent).clone();
            exRect.inflate(td.grabRange, td.grabRange);
            return exRect.containsPoint(td.mouseStart);
        }

        /**
         * Dispatches events associated with transformed client objects.
         * TransformToolEvent contains reference to interested TransformData object.
         * @eventType TransformToolEvent.EDGE_HIT dispatched when mouse cursor is close enought client object edges to let it to be scaled.
         * You can for example use it's hitEdges property to change cursor icon accordingly.
         */
        static public function get eventDispatcher():EventDispatcher 
        {
            return _eventDispatcher;
        }

        /**
         * Stage property on which mouse events will be proceded.
         * This will be set automaticly from client object (it it was null before).
         */
        static public function get stage():Stage 
        {
            return _stage;
        }

        static public function set stage(value:Stage):void 
        {
            if (_stage) {
                _stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMMove);
                _stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMUp);
                _stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMDown);
            }
            _stage = value;
            addStageListeners();
            if(checkEdgesOnMMove) value.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMMove);
        }
    }

}
```

TransformData class:

```
package utils  
{
    import flash.display.InteractiveObject;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
    /**
     * ...
     * @author Audionysos
     */
    public class TransformData 
    {
        public static const SCALE:uint = 1;
        public static const DRAG:uint = 2;
        public static const ROTATE:uint = 4;

        public static const TOP_EDGE:uint = 1;
        public static const RIGHT_EDGE:uint = 2;
        public static const BOTTOM_EDGE:uint = 4;
        public static const LEFT_EDGE:uint = 8;

        public var targetObject:InteractiveObject;
        public var grabRange:Number;
        public var sizeBounds:Rectangle;
        public var dragBounds:Rectangle;
        public var mouseStart:Point;
        public var mouseVector:Point;
        public var hitEdges:uint;
        public var edgesMask:uint;
        public var operations:uint;
        public var isTransforming:Boolean;

        private var _allowDrag:Boolean;
        private var isDraging:Boolean;

        public function TransformData(target:InteractiveObject, operations:uint = 3, edgesMask:uint = 15, sizeBounds:Rectangle = null, dragBounds:Rectangle = null, grabRange:Number = 5) 
        {
            targetObject = target;
            this.sizeBounds = sizeBounds;
            this.dragBounds = dragBounds;
            this.grabRange = grabRange;
            this.edgesMask = edgesMask;
            this.operations = operations;
        }

        public function updateMouseVector () {
            var mP:Point = new Point(targetObject.parent.mouseX, targetObject.parent.mouseY);
            if (!mouseStart) mouseStart = mP;
            mouseVector = mP.subtract(mouseStart);
            mouseStart = mP;
        }

        public function get allowDrag():Boolean 
        {
            return _allowDrag;
        }

        public function set allowDrag(value:Boolean):void 
        {
            if (_allowDrag && !value) {
                targetObject.stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMUp);
                targetObject.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMDown);
                if (isDraging) targetObject.stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMMove);
            }
            _allowDrag = value;
            if (value) targetObject.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMDown);
        }

        private function onMDown(e:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            isTransforming = true;
            mouseStart = TransformTool.getTargetMouse(this);
            targetObject.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMMove);
            targetObject.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMUp);
        }

        private function onMUp(e:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            isTransforming = false;
            targetObject.stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMMove);
        }

        private function onMMove(e:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            updateMouseVector();
            targetObject.x += mouseVector.x;
            targetObject.y += mouseVector.y;
            TransformTool.fixPlacement(this);
        }               
    }

}
```

TransformToolEvent:

```
package utils 
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author Audionysos
     */
    public class TransformToolEvent extends Event 
    {
        public static const EDGES_HIT:String = "edgesHit";
        private var _data:TransformData;

        public function TransformToolEvent(type:String, data:TransformData, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false) { 
            super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
            _data = data;
        } 

        public override function clone():Event { 
            return new TransformToolEvent(type, _data, bubbles, cancelable);
        } 

        public override function toString():String { 
            return formatToString("TransformToolEvent", "type", "bubbles", "cancelable", "eventPhase", "data"); 
        }

        public function get data():TransformData {
            return _data;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `target` or `currentTarget` propterty of the mouse-event to reference the instance that triggers the event, like this (i have not tested this code):

```
public function fl_WindowDrag(event: MouseEvent): void {
    event.currentTarget.startDrag();
}
```

this way you can add the event handler to multiple instances. You can read more about the [events properties here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html)

Comment: This will allow to drag individual elements of a window within the window, which is probably unwanted behaviour.

Comment: Ok, that works fine but I heve to use a lot of event listeners (two for each window) can I avoid this?

Comment: @null using currentTarget will always get the instance that got the handler assigned to it, ie the window

Comment: @LoreSchaeffer you only have to write two event listeners, one start and one stop. But you have to assign them to many windows. A good approach is to write a window class that handles all the events etc

Comment: so what have I to write before addEventListener? For now I have VTerminal that's the name of a window

Comment: @LoreSchaeffer you will have to have your instances organised in some way, for example in an array or as children of a movieclip. Then you can iterate (loop) over all those instances and do the addEventListener. Since i dont know your setup its difficult to guess a best aproach. How are they added to stage? That would be a good place to add the listener

Comment: I've an external class with all those functions and the addChild one to import MC from library, the full code is here: [link]http://pastebin.com/Fv1VTAyH

Comment: @LoreSchaeffer add this code to your question by clicking "edit" below it. Thanks